# How to average based on a Condition and append it to the bottom of a df with dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to average the OD600 values with the Condition = "Media" and append it to the bottom of the data frame using dplyer

Here is my attempt.

```
MOI0.2_72hr <- timepoints_0.2 %>%
  select(Well, Condition, OD600) %>%
  filter(Condition %in% c("Media", "B28B", "K824", "SBP2@2", "ANB28", "alpha_mix", "beta_mix", "gamma_mix", "3_Phage_Cocktail"))%>%
  group_by(Condition) %>%
  bind_rows(mutate(avg.media = mean(OD600)))
```

```
timepoints_0.2 <- structure(list(time = c(72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72), Well = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", 
"A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A12", "B1", "B2", "B3", 
"B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "B9", "B10", "B11", "B12", "C1", 
"C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10", "C11", 
"C12", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", 
"D10", "D11", "D12", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", 
"E8", "E9", "E10", "E11", "E12", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", 
"F6", "F7", "F8", "F9", "F10", "F11", "F12", "G1", "G2", "G3", 
"G4", "G5", "G6", "G7", "G8", "G9", "G10", "G11", "G12", "H1", 
"H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "H7", "H8", "H9", "H10", "H11", 
"H12"), OD600 = c(-0.007933, -0.007533, -0.007133, -0.007533, 
-0.008033, -0.007733, -0.007633, -0.007133, -0.007633, -0.007633, 
-0.007633, -0.008033, -0.005133, -0.000833, 0.661167, 0.906967, 
0.764667, 0.510767, 0.883767, 0.189067, 0.511467, 0.327367, 1.242367, 
-0.009133, -0.007533, -0.000133, 0.614567, 0.777767, 0.739967, 
0.464167, 0.783267, 0.234767, 0.466967, 0.322667, 1.172267, -0.007533, 
-0.006833, 0.000867, 0.001267, 0.799367, 0.712467, 0.456667, 
0.801867, 0.245667, 0.408867, 0.283067, 1.146567, -0.006633, 
-0.007933, 0.000267, 0.000267, 0.802567, 0.718767, 0.450067, 
0.771067, 0.243267, 0.416267, 0.321767, 1.143367, -0.007633, 
-0.006133, -0.000433, 0.217067, 0.808967, 0.739567, 0.442567, 
0.790567, 0.281767, 0.393667, 0.262767, 1.168667, -0.007433, 
-0.007833, 0.000267, 0.304367, 0.919567, 0.768367, 0.474967, 
0.766167, 0.214567, 0.445567, 0.206367, 1.207267, -0.007433, 
-0.008733, -0.007433, -0.007433, -0.007833, -0.008133, -0.007833, 
-0.008033, -0.006733, -0.008433, -0.007333, -0.009533, -0.009533
), Condition = c("Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", 
"Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", 
"Water", "Media ", "KB824_Lysate", "KB824", "SBP2@2", "ANB28", 
"alpha_mix", "beta_mix", "gamma_mix", "3_PhageCocktail", "B28B", 
"Water", "Water", "Media ", "KB824_Lysate", "KB824", "SBP2@2", 
"ANB28", "alpha_mix", "beta_mix", "gamma_mix", "3_PhageCocktail", 
"B28B", "Water", "Water", "Media ", "KB824_Lysate", "KB824", 
"SBP2@2", "ANB28", "alpha_mix", "beta_mix", "gamma_mix", "3_PhageCocktail", 
"B28B", "Water", "Water", "Media ", "KB824_Lysate", "KB824", 
"SBP2@2", "ANB28", "alpha_mix", "beta_mix", "gamma_mix", "3_PhageCocktail", 
"B28B", "Water", "Water", "Media ", "KB824_Lysate", "KB824", 
"SBP2@2", "ANB28", "alpha_mix", "beta_mix", "gamma_mix", "3_PhageCocktail", 
"B28B", "Water", "Water", "Media ", "KB824_Lysate", "KB824", 
"SBP2@2", "ANB28", "alpha_mix", "beta_mix", "gamma_mix", "3_PhageCocktail", 
"B28B", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", 
"Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water"
), Column = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), Letter = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", 
"H", "H", "H")), row.names = c(145L, 290L, 435L, 580L, 725L, 
870L, 1015L, 1160L, 1305L, 1450L, 1595L, 1740L, 1885L, 2030L, 
2175L, 2320L, 2465L, 2610L, 2755L, 2900L, 3045L, 3190L, 3335L, 
3480L, 3625L, 3770L, 3915L, 4060L, 4205L, 4350L, 4495L, 4640L, 
4785L, 4930L, 5075L, 5220L, 5365L, 5510L, 5655L, 5800L, 5945L, 
6090L, 6235L, 6380L, 6525L, 6670L, 6815L, 6960L, 7105L, 7250L, 
7395L, 7540L, 7685L, 7830L, 7975L, 8120L, 8265L, 8410L, 8555L, 
8700L, 8845L, 8990L, 9135L, 9280L, 9425L, 9570L, 9715L, 9860L, 
10005L, 10150L, 10295L, 10440L, 10585L, 10730L, 10875L, 11020L, 
11165L, 11310L, 11455L, 11600L, 11745L, 11890L, 12035L, 12180L, 
12325L, 12470L, 12615L, 12760L, 12905L, 13050L, 13195L, 13340L, 
13485L, 13630L, 13775L, 13920L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the average OD600 value per `Condition` value.

```
library(dplyr)
timepoints_0.2 %>% 
  group_by(Condition) %>% 
  summarize(avg.media = mean(OD600))
```

Output:

```
   Condition            avg.media
   <chr>                    <dbl>
 1 "3_PhageCocktail"  0.287      
 2 "alpha_mix"        0.799      
 3 "ANB28"            0.467      
 4 "B28B"             1.18       
 5 "beta_mix"         0.235      
 6 "gamma_mix"        0.440      
 7 "KB824"            0.836      
 8 "KB824_Lysate"     0.300      
 9 "Media "           0.000000333
10 "SBP2@2"           0.741      
11 "Water"           -0.00766
```

Appending this to the bottom of your frame makes little sense. Perhaps restate what you actually want to do?

Comment: I would like to remove the media blank from each OD600 reading, then make a boxplot of the data to show the distribution of the raw corrected values.